# Garbage Collection doesn't seem to be running on ASP.net MVC Application Pool

Tags: c#, asp.net, garbage-collection, .net-4.5, iis-8

I am having some weird issues with ASP.NET 4.5 garbage collection and any knowledge or guidance is appreciated.

I recently deployed a new web site about 2 weeks ago. When the site's application pool wakes up or recycled, the w3wp.exe memory will jump up to 500-600 MB and stay there. I've let it set for 10 to 20 minutes before I run GC.Collect() manually, and the w3wp.exe memory will instantly drop to 100-150 MB.

The server is Windows Server 2012, running IIS 8. The project is ASP.NET 4.5 MVC.

Is this normal behavior or is there something I'm missing?

UPDATE:
This box only has 4 GB or ram and I know it needs more, but I don't make those decisions. I am trying to work with what I have. We have about 8 other web sites running on this box. Most of them are small sites and run at 100 MB or less. We have a larger application also on this box which runs around 1600 MB.

Comment: From my understanding, GC will gobble up orphaned objects freeing memory when system memory is running low; its time to compact memory; a sizable `new` request comes along; or heavenly bodies are in alignment.  Servers I believe have a different GC policy too compared to WS.  You don't mention _how much_ memory the server has.  Maybe there is plenty and thus GC is not immediately required?

Comment: See update above. It's not a very beefy box and only has 4GB of ram on it.

Comment: @Micky is correct, It cannot be predict when GC gets collect the data. collection threshold/limits are updated based on the memory pressure/usage over the time.

Comment: I would be pretty nervous running production level code on a machine with that low amount of memory. You should just throw your app up on an azure VM with 16gb of ram and see what happens ;). You only pay for what you use.

Comment: @macm, I wish I could, but like I said, that's not my decision. I'm certain this would not be an issue on a better box. I guess it just me being impatient as the memory does go down over time. But didn't know why GC would just wait to collect, when running manually works. What was said above makes sense here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not unusual IMO. Essentially your application pool is building up all your in memory classes,caches etc. It is also compiling your pages on demand as they go. I am not sure how you are running your garbage collection on a production deploy while the app is running but unless the memory just keeps running, likely this is just the size of your app.

Comment: I have an action that only calls GC.Collect() in a controller that only I have access to.

Comment: I rarely if ever need to manually call for the GC. I would say that more often than not you should just let the GC handle its own requirements. This isn't classic asp or anything. The GC is pretty robust these days. I am going to guess your app is unstable if you are having to go to that level for solutions. Are you using page caching or loading data into memory? All that has a cost. https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/caching